# p-multiSelect change label in the drop down

Tags: angular, multi-select, primeng

Im trying to add some custom html text for each drop down label using multiselect of primeng.

Like for example in the below image, I need to add a small rectangular span displaying color before the label options of read and write.

[image]

Tried this below function, but it updates the default label and selectedItemsLabel instead of the drop down labels

```
  this.multi.updateLabel = function () {
  console.log(this);
  var label = this.value.length.toString()+ "P";
  this.valuesAsString = label;
}
```

Someone please help with this. Im very to new to using angular and primeng, any tricks or reference links would be great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

p-multiSelect option labels are data-bound. You can check examples [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/multiselect).

If you want to add more text to labels, they need to be added in the label property of the objects for the array bound to p-multiSelect options.

Example:

**ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter, Pipe, ChangeDetectorRef, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'input-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'input-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls:['input-overview-example.css']
})
export class InputOverviewExample {

  cars: SelectItem[];

  selectedCars: string[] = [];

  constructor() {
        this.cars = [];
        this.cars.push({label: 'Custom Label 1 Audi', value: 'Audi'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Custom Label 2 BMW', value: 'BMW'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Custom Label 3 Fiat', value: 'Fiat'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Custom Label 4 Ford', value: 'Ford'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Honda', value: 'Honda'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Jaguar', value: 'Jaguar'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Mercedes', value: 'Mercedes'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Renault', value: 'Renault'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'VW', value: 'VW'});
        this.cars.push({label: 'Volvo', value: 'Volvo'});
    }
}
```

**html:**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars"></p-multiSelect>

<p>Selected Cars: {{selectedCars}}</p>
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JIc2EkDz9HgymGQElHZ1?p=preview)

Comment: The above answer correct but there was some issue with explaining the question properly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I know that is old, but i found this trying to find a solution to **change p-multiSelect's label font-weight**. I noticed that my 'label' in styles.scss was affecting my p-multiSelect label and no matter what i had changed in the specific scss or style, did not changed. My co-worker gave me a tip about **::ng-deep** (I didn't know), and it solved! (I don't know exactly if it is the best solution)

```
::ng-deep p-multiSelect label {
  font-weight: normal !important;
}
```